# Phalcon - get result of count in PHQL

Tags: php, phalcon

I need to get number of rows from table as string.
I execute this code:

```
$phql  = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Model WHERE id = $this->id";
$count = $this->getModelsManager()->createQuery($phql)->execute();
```

Now `$count` is `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Complex` object. To get a proper result I need to do something like that:

```
$count[0]->{0}
```

In my opinion this is awful. Is there any other way to get this result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few solutions:

1) Use simple queries:

```
$count = $this->db->fetchOne('SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM products');
```

2) Model aggregations

```
$count = Products::count(
    "area = 'Testing'"
);
```

More info and methods: https://docs.phalconphp.com/ar/3.2/db-models in section **Generating Calculations**

3) If you insist of using `executeQuery()` you should add `getFirst()` in order to get only one result. Similar to PDO's `fetchOne()`.

```
$phql  = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM Models\Products";
$count = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql)->getFirst();
```